# change state if navlink is active

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my code. I using ReactJS and I trying change my state `isActive` if my navLink is active.

```
class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isActive: false,
    };
  }

  activeLink = () => {
    this.setState({
      isActive: true,
    });
  };

render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <MenuList>
          <NavLink to="/dashboard" isActive={this.activeLink}>
            <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem}>
              <ListItemIcon
                style={{ color: isActive ? 'blue' : 'black' }}
                className={classes.icon}
              >
                <HomeIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText
                classes={{ primary: classes.primary }}
                inset
                primary={<FormattedMessage {...messages.dashboardItem} />}
              />
            </MenuItem>
          </NavLink>
...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your actual question? What is the output you're seeing and what do you see instead? A tip: You improve your chances of a helpful answer significantly if you provide a [mcve], because people can test-drive your code and can easier see what is wrong.

Comment: Well if I get it, you want to change the state of the navlink when it gets into the DOM. This navlink belongs to which framwork? It probably should have an api propria that indicates some states, could you add this information to your question?

Answer (score 0):

The `isActive` attribute on a `NavLink` is a function for adding extra logic to say whether the navlink should be active or not, it's not a function to be triggered if the navlink is active like I believe you are trying to use it for.

You can use it to do a standard check for location match and also call setState if you want, though it's not what it's technically designed for:

```
activeLink = match => {
    if (!match) return false;
    this.setState({
       isActive: true,
    });
    return true;
};
```